# How to process image before applying bwlabel?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, medical

```
I = imread('Sub1.png');
figure, imshow(I);
I = imcomplement(I);
I = double(I)/255;
I = adapthisteq(I,'clipLimit',0.0003,'Distribution','exponential');
k = 12;
beta = 2;
maxIter = 100;
for i=1:length(beta)
   [seg,prob,mu,sigma,it(i)] = ICM(I, k, beta(i), maxIter,5);
   pr(i) = prob(end);
   hold on;
end
figure, imshow(seg,[]);
```

and ICM function is defined as

```
function [segmented_image,prob,mu,sigma,iter] = ICM(image, k, beta, max_iterations, neigh)
    [width, height, bands] = size(image);
    image = imstack2vectors(image);
    segmented_image = init(image,k,1);
    clear c;
    iter = 0;
    seg_old = segmented_image;

    while(iter < max_iterations)
        [mu, sigma] = stats(image, segmented_image, k);

        E1 = energy1(image,mu,sigma,k);
        E2 = energy2(segmented_image, beta, width, height, k);
        E = E1 + E2;
        [p2,~] = min(E2,[],2);
        [p1,~] = min(E1,[],2);

        [p,segmented_image] = min(E,[],2);
        prob(iter+1) = sum(p);

        %find mismatch with previous step
        [c,~] = find(seg_old~=segmented_image);
        mismatch = (numel(c)/numel(segmented_image))*100;
        if mismatch<0.1
            iter
            break;
        end
        iter = iter + 1;
        seg_old = segmented_image;
    end
    segmented_image = reshape(segmented_image,[width height]);
end
```

Output of my algorithm is a logical matrix (`seg`) of size 305-by-305. When I use

```
imshow(seg,[]);
```

I am able to display the image. It shows different component with varying gray value. But `bwlabel` returns 1. I want to display the connected components. I think `bwlabel` thresholds the image to 1. `unique(seg)` returns values 1 to 10 since number of classes used in k-means is 10. I used

```
[label n] = bwlabel(seg);
RGB = label2rgb(label);
figure, imshow(RGB);
```

I need all the ellipse-like structures which are in between the two squares close to the middle of the image. I don't know the number of classes present in it.

Input image:

[image: Input Image]

Ground truth:

[image: Groundtruth]

My output:

[image: Output]

Comment: I want to use this code +some other code to get ellipse like structure.bwlabel is not compulsory but ICM is compulsory

Comment: No.I dont know how to implement it.also i have ground truth as a binary mask

Comment: I can answer the question that how the `seg` image can be segmented to different objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explode the label image to different connected components you need to use a loop to extract labels for each class and sum label images to get the `out` label image.

```
u = unique(seg(:));
out = zeros(size(seg));
num_objs = 0;
for k = 1: numel(u)
    mask = seg==u(k);
    [L,N] = bwlabel(mask);
    L(mask) = L(mask) + num_objs;
    out = out + L;
    num_objs = num_objs + N ;
end
mp = jet(num_objs);
figure,imshow(out,mp)
```

Something like this is produced:

[image: connected components]

Comment: I dont know.. :)

Comment: @user1234 They are more like rectangles than ellipses.

Comment: If I have more time I would be glad if I can search the literature or consult specialized forums. I am sure the community contains the ones that are specialist in (medical) image processing and they like help you. But also it depends on how you format and explain your question.

Comment: What do you expect me to do?

Comment: I don't know. I suggest to search the literature to get more insights.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do everything out of scratch. I wish it is of some help.

I have a treatment chain that get at first contours with parameters tuned on a trial-and-error basis, I confess. The last "image" is given at the bottom ; with it, you can easily select the connected components and do for example a reconstruction by markers using "imreconstruct" operator.

```
clear all;close all;
I = imread('C:\Users\jean-marie.becker\Desktop\imagesJPG10\spinalchord.jpg');
figure,imshow(I);
J = I(:,:,1);% select the blue channel because jpg image
J=double(J<50);% I haven't inverted the image
figure, imshow(J);
se = strel('disk',5);
J=J-imopen(J,se);
figure, imshow(J);
J=imopen(J,ones(1,15));% privilegizes long horizontal strokes
figure, imshow(J);
K=imdilate(J,ones(20,1),'same');
% connects verticaly not-to-far horizontal "segments"
figure, imshow(K);
```

[image]

Comment: sir i dont know how to apply imreconstruct .i dont know marker controlled watershed.which is the input image you take.can you  help me to proceed further

Comment: i need elipse like region.I think u r trying to extract rectangular region